# snowflake-python error while executing snowflake SQL statement in python

Tags: python, sql, dynamic, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I get this error why i try to execute a dynamic sql just built while executing the program

> 'SnowflakeCursor' object has no attribute 'strip'

This is the dynamic SQL

```
Alter_add_dyn_sql="SELECT 'ALTER TABLE "+schema+"."+object_name+" ADD(COL_Y VARCHAR2(100));' FROM DUAL;"
```

Here is the call to execute the cursor i have opened

This is the dynamic SQL

```
 cs_dev_cdw=dev_cdw_conn.cursor()
 print(Alter_add_dyn_sql)                         
 Alt_add_sql=cs_dev_cdw.execute(Alter_add_dyn_sql)
 print(Alt_add_sql)

   output: Alter_add_dyn_sql="SELECT 'ALTER TABLE "+schema+"."+object_name+" ADD(COL_Y 
    VARCHAR2(100));' FROM DUAL;"
 Alt_add_sql=cs_dev_cdw.execute(Alter_add_dyn_sql)
 execute error:
 'SnowflakeCursor' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

dev_cdw_conn definition

```
dev_cdw_conn = sf.connect (dev_cdw_database=config.dev_cdw_database,dev_warehouse=config.dev_warehouse,user=config.username,password=config.password,account=config.account,dev_role=config.dev_cdw_role)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace? I think some important code is missing

Comment: hi filipe I believe i have the relavent sections. Could you please clarify what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your error, but I do see one problem in your code: you don't have to construct the SQL statement by selecting from dual. You can just pass in the SQL statement as a string:

```
Alter_add_dyn_sql='ALTER TABLE '+schema+'.'+object_name+' ADD(COL_Y VARCHAR2(100));'
```

Comment: Thanks Maja. I tried as you suggested. Here is it is

Comment: Alter_add_dyn_sql='ALTER TABLE '+schema+'.'+object_name+' ADD(COL_Y VARCHAR2(100));'

Comment: [8:22 AM] Srinivasa Raghavan
    
Alter_add_dyn_sql_str=Alter_add_dyn_sql.replace('\n','')

​[8:22 AM] Srinivasa Raghavan
    
cs_dev_cdw = dev_cdw_conn.cursor()            
print(Alter_add_dyn_sql.replace('\n',''))   
cs_dev_cdw.execute(cs_dev_cdw,Alter_add_dyn_sql_str)
Generated SQL statement - > ALTER TABLE DW.BATCH_CONTROL ADD(COL_Y VARCHAR2(100));
Still Errors out as  -> 'SnowflakeCursor' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Hi Maja - I slightly changed the cursor invoking statement and execution statement. I am good now. It worked. Thanks for your input on simplfying the SQL. Here is my revised code that worked for cursor

Comment: dev_cdw_execute_query(dev_cdw_conn,Alter_add_dyn_sql_str)

Comment: Definition for the function

Comment: def dev_cdw_execute_query(dev_cdw_conn,query):
    cs_dev_cdw = dev_cdw_conn.cursor()
    cs_dev_cdw.execute(query)
    print("Dev cdw connection cursor opened")